# How to get the page source with Mechanize/Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm logged into a webpage/servlet using Mechanize.

I have a page object:

```
jobShortListPg = agent.get(addressOfPage)
```

When I use:

```
puts jobShortListPg
```

I get the "mechanized" version of the page which I don't want:

```
#<Mechanize::Page::Link "Home" "blahICScriptProgramName=WEBLIB_MENU.ISCRIPT3.FieldFormula.IScript_DrillDown&target=main0&Level=0&RL=&navc=3171">
```

How do I get the HTML source of the page instead?

Comment: In Ruby we use snake_case, not camelCase for variables or method names. ItIsAReadabilityThing.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `.body`:

```
puts jobShortListPg.body
```

Comment: I still get the mechanized version of the page :(.

Comment: Are you sure you did `.body` on the page that was returned by `.get`? I get a pure string back. `Mechanize.new.get("http://www.google.com").body.class` => `String`

Comment: Silly me, I was working on the wrong file. Did .body on the right file and it worked! Thank you Dogbert!

Comment: Mechanized version is better than source. they have many helpers in them

Comment: @carbonr unless calling an API and the source is the JSON you actually need

Answer (score 2):

Use the `content` method of the page object.

```
jobShortListPg.content
```

Answer (score 0):

In Nokogiri use [`to_s`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#to_s-instance_method) or [`to_html`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#to_html-instance_method) on the main document Node:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>foo</body>
</html>
EOT

doc.to_html
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n" +
#    "<html>\n" +
#    "  <head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"></head>\n" +
#    "  <body>foo</body>\n" +
#    "</html>\n"
```

or:

```
doc.to_s
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n" +
#    "<html>\n" +
#    "  <head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"></head>\n" +
#    "  <body>foo</body>\n" +
#    "</html>\n"
```

If it distracts you to see the embedded new-lines, this might help:

```
puts doc.to_s

# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >>   <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>
# >>   <body>foo</body>
# >> </html>
```