# Web scraping HTML in a Rails app

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping

I'm trying to get my rails app to fetch the HTML source of a web page.

I want to get all of the HTML from a URI like `/news_articles/7` into a string.

I tried using something like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) but it seems to lock mutex.

The purpose for this is to send a string of HTML to Amazon's [SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/).

Thanks

Comment: 1) I cannot parse your **... get all of the HTML a URI ...**. 2) What is Nokugiri? 3) **It seem** => It seems 4) **reason** => purpose

Comment: You can just go to your app, right-click and `view source`?

Comment: You probably want to use something like `ActionMailer` with SES, instead of trying to render a page into a string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798437/using-amazon-ses-with-rails-actionmailer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Nokogiri` in combination with `Mechanize` will serve you well.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'mechanize'
```

**controller**

```
agent = Mechanize.new()
# allow the agent to follow redirects
agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
# get the desired page
page = agent.get('http://www.mysite.com/new_articles/7')
# output its html
page.body
```

[Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487101/how-to-get-the-page-source-with-mechanize-nokogiri)

Comment: I think he's trying to run this from within a Rails request cycle. Hence he will deadlock the whole Rails app. That's his main problem.

Comment: Jup that makes more sense, I guess you provided the right link